# Setting up kiwi for multiple target

Tags: ios, objective-c, testing, bdd, kiwi

I have a xcode project that has 2 targets for iPad and iPhone build.

I have followed the installation instructions and installed `kiwi` via `cocoapods`.

When I create a new test target "Product Name", xcode created a folder group and it comes with single test case file with an example. This folder contains "Supporting Files".

Couple of questions here:

1. Do I need to keep the "Supporting Files" group?
2. When I launch the test via cmd-U, it launches my iPad build. How do I configure cmd-U or have different test target for my iPad and iPhone targets?

**UPDATE**

Following the installation instruction, I created another test target and edited the scheme for my iPhone build and added the new target under "Test". It seems to work.

Does that mean if I want to have a common test for common interfaces or libraries, I have to create yet another target and associate with both schemes?